# How to deal with client input your site?

Tags: entries, updating

Our client wants a poll on the website.
How can I deal with client input and update the entry?
I found the [Entry-Form example](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form), but this doesn't work.

The title field is the question and the admin can add answers with a matrix field. Within the matrix fields there are 2 fields: answer and totalVotes

This is my code:

```twig
<form class="poll__questions" method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ craft.request.getPath }}?success=√">
    <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="38">
    <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ pollentry.id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">

    <ul>
    {{% for answer in pollentry.answers %}
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="fields[answers][{{ answer.id }}][fields][totalVotes]" value="{{ answer.totalVotes + 1 }}"> {{ answer.answer }}</label></li>
    {% endfor %}}
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" class="button button--third">Vote</button>
</form>
```

Does anybody know why this doesn't work. It submits the form without visible errors, but it doens't update the entry.

Comment: The EntryModel is likely failing validation somewhere.  If it is, and you check your craft/storage/runtime/logs folder, you can see where that is happening.

Comment: Did the logs help you identify your problem?

Comment: No this didn't help me with my problem. I solved it with a plugin and not with matrix fields, but with normal fields.

Comment: @sneeky Would you mind sharing your solution as an answer? Asking and answering your own questions is totally legit!

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but one thing that might help you diagnose the problem, is to output all the return errors (without having to define it on each field as the example templates do).

```
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
    {% if errors %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import errorList %}

{% if account is defined %}
    {{ errorList(account.getAllErrors()) }}
{% endif %}

{% if entry is defined %}
    {{ errorList(entry.getAllErrors()) }}
{% endif %}
```

A User Model named 'account' is returned by default from a failed `users/saveUser` post action, and an Entry Model named 'entry' is returned by default from a failed `entries/saveEntry` post action.

I have also found the [Inpector](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/inspector) plug-in extremely helpful. You can then add `{{ account | inspect }}` or `{{ entry | inspect }}` within the `if` statements above to get more info.