# Are there any poll plugins for Craft CMS?

Tags: plugins

Since many of us are coming from EE, I will reference these EE addons as examples:
- channel polls
- vwm polls

I found this question but it didn't help much:
[How to deal with client input your site?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/641/how-to-deal-with-client-input-your-site)

Also there is UPVOTE plugin but it's not really polls.
https://www.doublesecretagency.com/plugins/upvote

It is important that it works like field type and that you can add as many options as you need.

Thank you

Comment: Hey @wmd, would you mind elaborating on what you feel the requirements of a poll are that a standard form doesn't do?

Comment: You could _possibly_ use Upvote to handle polling. Feel free to email me at support@doublesecretagency.com, and I'll help you walk through it.

Answer (score 4):

The only public listing of plugins that I'm aware of is on the [straightupcraft site](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins) — so if nothing is there that meets your requirements then probably not. New plugins are getting added all the time though.

Depending on your requirements, developing a custom solution would probably not be too difficult though. If you want to give it a shot and have questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

I need it too and found this: https://github.com/gregorterrill/gtpoll

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score -4):

Poll need to work as field type  so it can be done per entry

as https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/channel-polls
or 
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vwm-polls

Its important to not have row limits about voting options..

Comment: How would you integrate these EE plugins into Craft? I think you accidentally posted this to the wrong SE.

Comment: Easy, Just plug and play :)

this two where posted beacuse of funcionality so people get better picture what kind of  Poll we need on Craft

Comment: @Jozo Those are both links to [ExpressionEngine](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine) plugins, not [Craft](http://buildwithcraft.com/) plugins. Craft and ExpressionEngine are completely separate CMS's, their plugins are not compatible. Unless someone were to **port** an EE plugin to Craft, it is of no real use to someone running Craft.

Comment: You, so serious :)